# What techniques have been shown to improve a self-defeatist attitude?

Tags: clinical-psychology, therapy

I suppose this is a bit relative to each and every person, but in general those who are defeatists tend to view the potential outcomes of new actions negatively. Have any therapy techniques been shown to counter this sort of thinking and behavior?